# Table for a little quantity of registers... I don´t would like to do that

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a Brazilian, sorry for my English.

I have a Pet and Pet_Model models. Both have Colors.
I don´t would like to make a table with 4, 5 colors (registers).

Firstly, I did a Color model (without database table) with an array attribute colors with hashes of name color and his code:

```
 class Color
        def colors  
            [{:name => 'blue', :cod => '#FF9'}, {...}, ...]  
        end
 end
```

And I used a 'fields_for :colors' in the form Pet erb.

But I had problems to rescue these data from database. Then I doing think make a table for Colors. But this table will contain only 4, 5 registers... Understand me?

What is the best solution? Create or not create a table for these colors?

Thanks

[EDIT]

Are relevant...

VIEW

```
<% for color in Color::COLORS.keys %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'pet[colors][]', color %>
  <%= color %><br/>
<% end -%>
```

MODEL

```
class Pet < ActiveRecord::Base
    serialize :colors
end
```

Comment: I'm also Brazilian, and I'm finding it hard to understand your question. But probably "register" means "record"; also "Then I doing think make" means "So I'm thinking about creating".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really not sure if I understand your question, but assuming that you have a predefined hash of colors and you want to be able to use this hash to set a color for your pets and pet models.

If this selection of colors doesn't change, you could maybe use a constant containing the colors and a bitmask to store the selected color with your models — then you wouldn't need a colors table.
Ryan Bates has a nice screencast which uses this technique: http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association

In your case you'd need probably redefine the hash to look something like this

```
{ "red" => "#f00", "blue" => "#ff9", … }
```

And then only deal the keys

```
{ "red" => "#f00", "blue" => "#ff9", … }.keys # -> ["red", "blue", …]
```

Am I anywhere close to what you need?

Comment: Thanks! I got it.  
But, the checkbox are unchecked in edit page. The register has colors, but in edit page they aren´t displayed (checked checkbox in this case).

Comment: Thanks! I'm still not quite sure what's going on there now, though. What's actually now stored in a Pet row as color(s)? The plural seems to indicate that one Pet can have multiple colors? — Generally speaking: The third parameter for `check_box_tag` is a boolean and decides if the box is checked or not. So you could do something like `check_box_tag 'pet[colors][]', color, @pet.colors.has_key?(color)` if you know what I mean.